# Variável com ponteiro é declarada nula, porém função membro executa normalmente

Tags: c++, exceção, ponteiro

Abaixo segue um exemplo do código que eu estou tentando executar.

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
    void teste(){
        cout << "Teste" << endl;
    } 
};


int main(){
    A *pA = NULL;

    pA->teste();
    return 0;
}

//end main.cpp
```

Uma vez que declaro o ponteiro `*pA` como nulo, esperava que o programa desse erro. Porém, o mesmo executa o normalmente e exibe a mensagem "Teste".

Por que o programa executa normalmente em vez de lançar um erro to tipo *null pointer exception*?

Estou utilizando a plataforma Qt5 no Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Por que você acha que deveria dar uma exceção?

O ponteiro é necessário para referenciar-se para uma estrutura de dados, ou seja, para um estado, para dados na memória. Para acessar o comportamento da classe, ou seja, os seus métodos. o ponteiro não precisa referenciando para nenhuma posição da memória. Pelo tipo o compilador sabe onde está o código dos métodos que são independentes da instância.

O código fica em uma área estática (fixa) na memória e o progressivamente o compilador, com o *linkador*, e depois a carga do executável pelo sistema operacional determinarão o endereço do código. Os métodos estão disponíveis sempre na aplicação, mesmo que você não tenha criado uma instância válida.

Ainda assim poderia gerar uma exceção **dentro** do método se ele estivesse tentando acessar algum estado da classe. Mas neste caso não está, então não tem porque dar erro.

O que você está mandando fazer é chamar o método `teste()` do tipo `A` que por acaso está sendo referenciado pela variável `pA` mas como a classe não tem dados, nada precisa ser armazenado na memória para sua execução. Se nada precisa ser armazenado, não precisa ter nenhum endereço de memória para referenciar-se, então um `NULL` cai bem. E como durante a execução do método você apenas faz acesso a um *stream* enviando um literal *string* e o fim de linha, não acessa dado algum da instância (e nem poderia, já que não existe), não precisa acessar nada na memória, não precisa de um endereço válido na variável.

Então o ocorrido é o lógico. Seria estranho que uma exceção fosse lançada. Experimente criar um campo com estado na classe e acessá-lo no `teste()` ou diretamente no `main()` e veja o que acontece.

Em C++ não há necessidade e não é recomendado criar classes sem estado, prefira utilizar funções simples e se precisar organizar funções relacionadas em uma única unidade lógica use `namespace`. C++ não é Java.

Não esqueça de ler o complemento no comentário do Guilherme Bernal abaixo sobre comportamento indefinido que é altamente indesejável (o comportamento, não o comentário do Guilherme :) ). Ele é muito importante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Está era a resposta que eu tinha em mente em vista dos resultados. Porém, esperava que em C++ fosse possível acessar os métodos de uma classe, somente, através de métodos estáticos quando não há uma instância definida (assim como em Java).
Grato pela explicação.

Comment: @RaelMendez O C++ é mais "flexível" neste sentido. De qualquer forma lembre-se que, em geral, uma classe sem dados não faz muito sentido. Pelo menos não em C++. Em Java até faz, já que ela quer criar a ilusão que é tudo orientado a objeto. Claro que eu entendo que você está só testando coisas e não colocando isto em produção :)

Comment: Complementando a resposta: O ponto é que a linguagem não fará nenhum tipo de checagem em runtime sobre o seu código. Isso permite que seja executado na maior velocidade possível (enquanto que uma linguagem como java teria que adicionar checagens de null a cada chamada de função (se o compilador não puder provar estaticamente)). Mas note: o comportamento de chamar uma função em um objeto null é indefinido. No seu caso **particular** funciona. Mas em muitos outros pode não funcionar. Ou pior: corromper silenciosamente outra parte não relacionada da memória. Nunca use comportamento indefinido.

Comment: Apenas uma nota histórica: Chamar uma função membro que não acesse o objeto de fato funciona com o objeto nulo (embora não seja enforçado por nada). Antes da criação das funções membro estáticas ([no Cfront 2.0, em 1989](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history)) era comum se utilizar dessa técnica para emular funções estáticas. Por exemplo, `Factory::create()` podia ser substituido por `((Factory*)NULL)->create()` e alcançar o mesmo efeito prático. Logo é até possível que veja esse "erro" em código extremamente legado.